# Are there any tools / "life hacks" to cut sphere-shaped potatoes and carrots?

Tags: equipment, salad

[Salad Olivier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivier_salad) - The modern version contains peas, potatoes, carrot, eggs, etc.

It would be cool to cut everything into same-size spheres...

Comment: You mention peas, so that sounds like a [melon baller](https://www.google.com/search?q=melon+baller) would be too big. Also carrots are quite hard which would make it more difficult

Comment: There is a classic very french knife skill called tournee that is all about making everything the shape of very american footballs. As to the peas: Maybe make some kind of patty/fritter of them and saute it as a topping.

Answer (score 3):

I think @ChrisH is on to something with the melon baller. They come in various sizes such as 1 cm, 1/2", 3 cm, and 1", to name a few. While 1 cm is the smallest I could find, it will still be larger than the peas which have an average size of .5 cm.

That said, you could use the 1 cm or 1/2" melon baller for the rest of your veggies and the egg. Of course, the egg will have to be cooked before scooping. But I think that is the answer for the carrots, too. Clean them and cook them whole before scooping.

While you could go either way with the potatoes, I think I would peel and cook them first.

With the harder veggies, you want to be sure they are fully cooked, but be sure not to *over*cook them. Too soft and the scooping could be a disaster.

The other option for the harder vegetables would be to partially cook them, scoop the balls out, and then finish cooking to your desired doneness.

Answer (score 3):

I used to have a potato peeling machine that tumbled potatoes around a grater-surface, was kind of useless for just peeling, but I enjoyed using it to create perfectly spherical potatoes and carrots. I cut them in equally long, wide and deep pieces (but could still be a cylinder), and put them in for quite a while. Sometimes I had to help the machine a bit and nick some edges off some of them that wouldn't become round.

Comment: How small are the finished spheres?

Comment: It was a small machine, so about an inch (2.4 cm) gave the best result, so carrots could just be cylinders of a carrot. I think anything pea-sized wouldn't have the weight to grate itself properly.